# Compare two .json files in Java?

Tags: java, json, collections

Firstly I am new to handling with JSON. Now i am going to compare two .json files by using java. If any one familiar with this, Could you please guide me the best approach. Thanks in advance.

My json files are look like below.

```
file1.json
[{
    "GEO_ENERGY_RESOURCES_LIMITED": {
      "Total Assets Consolidated": "309,074,176",
      "Total Assets Company": "226,919,588",
      "Date": "31-Dec-16",
      "Currency": "US Dollar",
      "Total Revenue Consolidated": "182,108,648",
      "Total Revenue Company": "Not Found",
      "RDate": "31-Dec-16"
    }
  },
  {
    "GLOBAL_LOGISTIC_PROPERTIES_LIMITED": {
      "Total Assets Consolidated": "21,759,755,000",
      "Total Assets Company": "9,233,746,000",
      "Date": "31-Mar-17",
      "Currency": "US Dollar",
      "Total Revenue Consolidated": "886820000",
      "Total Revenue Company": "Not Found",
      "RDate": "31-Mar-17"
    }
  }]

file2.json
[{
    "GEO_ENERGY_RESOURCES_LIMITED": {
      "Total Assets Consolidated": "",
      "Total Assets Company": "226,919,588",
      "Date": "01-Dec-16",
      "Currency": "US Dollar",
      "Total Revenue Consolidated": "182,108,648",
      "Total Revenue Company": "Not Found",
      "RDate": "31-Dec-16"
    }
  },
  {
    "GLOBAL_LOGISTIC_PROPERTIES_LIMITED": {
      "Total Assets Consolidated": "21,759,755,000",
      "Total Assets Company": "9,233,746,000",
      "Date": "31-Mar-17",
      "Currency": "US Dollar",
      "Total Revenue Consolidated": "",
      "Total Revenue Company": "Not Found",
      "RDate": "31-Mar-17"
    }
  }]
```

Comment: What is your objective? To just check whether they are identical or something else?

Comment: @Prabhav Thanks to reply. Here my objective is to check the data is matching or not. If it is not matching i supposed to return difference of that values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to convert json to model class. Here is [example](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

First, create model:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "user")
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String username;
    private int age;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Then convert json to object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'bejond', 'age': 18}";
Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Person.class);
```

Now you get person, you can get value and compare to each other. You can use @JsonPropery and other annotations to map attributes to json properties, even though their names are different.

Comment: Thank you so much,I did similarly like this and finally got it.